# Библиотеки в C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net

Какие библиотеки в C#/.NET можно использовать для статистики / математических вычислений? Я знаю, есть ML.NET, TensorFlowSharp, Accord.NET, Microsoft Azure ML Studio, Amazon Machine Learning. Может быть, было что-то упущено?

Comment: Подобного рода вопросы на ru so являются оффтопиком. Сформулируйте конкретную задачу коотрую вам нужно решить - это хорошая стартовая точка для подобных вопросов.

Comment: `Желательно как можно более подробный список.` вы сайтом ошиблись, тут помогают решать проблемы с кодом, а не ищут за вас в гугле.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Про `System.Math`/`System.MathF` тоже не стоит забывать.

Comment: `Я знаю, есть ML.NET, TensorFlowSharp, Accord.NET, Microsoft Azure ML Studio, Amazon Machine Learning. Может быть, было что-то упущено?` - вам мало? Напишите свою, вон в .NET 6 даже AVX-VNNI подвезут.

Comment: Numpy. На нугете по запросу math находится много либ.

Comment: Для моей задачи нужен полный, как можно более подробный список.  Так как у меня нет практического опыта работы с C#, хотелось бы узнать информацию от специалистов, потому что гугл показывает далеко не все плюс непонятно, насколько загугленное широко используется на практике

Comment: Чем вас тогда отает ниже не устраивает? Начните хоть с чего-нибудь.

Comment: Подробный список - это сотни библиотек. Зачем он вам? Что вы будете делать с этим огромным списком?

Answer (score 1):

Есть, к примеру, [Accord.NET](http://accord-framework.net/), но там чистой статистики не так много, а больше машинного обучения. Вообще довольно универсальная библиотека для много чего, советую ознакомиться.